# Install previous versions of R on ubuntu

Tags: r, ubuntu

I am wanting to use RHadoop packages(rmr, rhdfs, rhbase) on my ubuntu server. These only work with the older version of R 2.15.0 and not on the current 3.0.1 version. I have created a mirror which allowed me to install the 3.0.1 version.

```
sudo apt-get install r-base-dev
```

What do I need to change here to get the 2.15.0 version of R?

I have tried using the links but i think I might need to access a new mirror since the link to both downloads are different.

current mirror:

```
deb http://cran.cnr.berkeley.edu/bin/linux/ubuntu precise/
```

I assume its getting the most recent file and executing it:

http: //cran.cnr.berkeley.edu/bin/linux/ubuntu/precise/r-base-dev_3.0.1-5precise0_all.deb

The link I want it to follow and install

http: //cran.cnr.berkeley.edu/src/base/R-2/R-2.15.0.tar.gz

After berkeley.edu it is all different but in my mirror it would stay the same. I have tried changing my mirror but haven't had any luck.

If anyone has any suggestions or can lead me down the right path that would greatly help.

-Joey

Comment: This RStudio support blog post might be helpful as well [Installing multiple versions of R on Linux](https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/215488098-Installing-multiple-versions-of-R-on-Linux).

Answer (score 5):

You will find previous **binary builds** for Ubuntu in the standard directory, just by hand:

```
 https://cran.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu/
```

You can always download them manually and then tell the package management system to put them 'on hold', ie to not upgrade.  See eg `man dpkg` for the `dpkg --set-selection` and the `hold` state.

Comment: Its not to stop it from updating to the newest package, its downloading the older version so that I can use it. So again How do I get the 2.15.0 R version downloaded on my Ubuntu cloud? I know where to find the file, http: //cran.cnr.berkeley.edu/src/base/R-2/R-2.15.0.tar.gz, but when I try to call it to install there are error saying it cant find the file path. 
Does anyone know how to get the file downloaded? maybe it is changing the 'deb' file?

Comment: You are confusing **binaries** and **sources**, compare your URL with the one in my answer.

Comment: Yea I am a bit confused. I see that our URLs are different yours is quantal and mine is precise. I see that there are a bunch of different versions and file types. What I'm stuck on is how to install one of those onto my ubuntu server. Am I supposed to change the deb file that I made for the mirror? how do I call it also. I am really stuck right now so anything helps. If only my R packages worked on the newest version.

Answer (score 3):

You find outdated versions of R at the CRAN page:

http://cran.r-project.org/sources.html

Following a couple of links:

http://cran.r-project.org/src/base/R-2/R-2.15.0.tar.gz

I suppose it is possible that that Debian/Ubuntu repository has the Make files to drive the compilation from source. If not, you can probably find one on the R-Debian mailing list.

Comment: I think you should read `INSTALL` file once you download the zipped link.

Comment: @agstudy: I'm not a Ubuntu user so I was unsure if the included make and configure files needed any tweaking, but from your comment I take it that they don't?

Comment: yes they don't include a make file but easy to create one. For SIMPLE COMPILATION you should unpack the R sources and go
to the top directory.  Issue the following commands:`./configure` and `make`( this is mainly what it is written in the `INSTALL` file)