# Forecast package not working on Databricks (R-version 3.5.2)

Tags: r, ubuntu, databricks, azure-databricks

I installed the 'forecast' package in a Databricks environment a few days back. It was working fine until this morning when I restarted the cluster. Now, I can't install the package anymore. Could someone help with this?

Have already tried upgrading the current R version (3.5.2) to the latest (3.6.0). That would require upgrading the current Ubuntu version too, which I don't think is possible, since that is the version Databricks is linked to. If there's a way to upgrade the Ubuntu version as well, do let me know.

[Here's a screenshot of the error:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SUU1Q.png)

Comment: Please post the error message or screenshot of the same. Thanks..

Comment: In the meantime, please use `.libPaths()` to check the library path of your packages and go to the folder, delete the package folder completely, restart R and install the package - this would solve the problem if the package installation is corrupted

Comment: Hi @SaiPrabhanjanReddy!!
The issue with this package is only in the Databricks  - it's working just fine in RStudio. I've attached a screenshot of the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FROM THE SCREENSHOT, The 'quadprog' latest version 1.5-5 supports only >= R-3.6 version as yours is R-3.5.2, I would suggest you to download old binaries from CRAN for quadprog and install (refer [Install previous versions of R on ubuntu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17935292/install-previous-versions-of-r-on-ubuntu))

After installing quadprog, go for the other packages installation. If same error persists, please repeat above step for that packages too :)

If you are trying this operation through R Console, you can use

```
packageurl <- "https://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/quadprog/quadprog_1.5-4.tar.gz"
install.packages(packageurl, repos=NULL, type="source")
```

Comment: Thanks for letting me know. Good day!