# Install specific R version on Ubuntu-16.04

Tags: r, docker, ubuntu, ubuntu-16.04

I'm a complete novice with Ubuntu. I've found questions that are the same as mine but I'm finding the advice difficult to follow.

---

**Context**

We have a dockerfile running from `ubuntu:16.04`. On this we install R along with other tools e.g git & sql.

The current method is to add this repo: `add-apt-repository ppa:marutter/rrutter3.5` and call `apt-get install r-base`

This works fine but we're really worried about the R versions. Our code is being used in production on `3.5.2` R version. When we re-build the Docker image from scratch now the repo automatically updates us to `3.6.0`. We want to be able to fix the R version until a later release when we can test `3.6.0` more

I've looked at https://hub.docker.com/_/r-base/, and can build a dockerfile with `FROM r-base:3.5.2` with no problems. But combining it with my current dockerfile that installs the other tools e.g. git, is beyond me

---

**Research**

https://superuser.com/questions/1396699/how-to-install-r-3-5-1-on-ubuntu-16-with-apt-get

> They say there is a way of pointing at the R version required and installing it from Source. Ideally I'd like to find a repository I can install the specific version from. If I can't, is this straightforward to do?

[Install previous versions of R on ubuntu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17935292/install-previous-versions-of-r-on-ubuntu)

> The answer was hard for me to understand without more knowledge of ubuntu.

https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu/README.html

> It links to this page, but I can't see how I would pick the R version. It only mentions 3.6 & 3.4

https://askubuntu.com/questions/435232/install-older-version-of-software-and-dependencies

> In this one they specify `r-base=3.0.2-1precise0`. I tried this with `r-base=3.5.2`, but I'm guessing I need to change my repository from rrutter

---

I've spent a lot of time Googling this, but it's a bit of a minefield. Any guidance would be great! If I'm missing anything useful, I apologise. Let me know and I'll update my post

Best,
Jonny

Answer (score 2):

You can create a Dockerfile using the `r-base` image and installing `git`:

```
FROM r-base:3.5.2

RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get upgrade -y && \
    apt-get install -y git
```

Comment: There is quite a lot in our current dockerfile which is using `From ubuntu:16.04` as the base. Wouldn't I have to re-do the whole dockerfile, to accomodate R, by changing the base image? Not saying this is a bad idea, we may have to try this. It just feels a bit strange to be forced in to using an R image base

Comment: It is actually a good practice to use a more specific base image, it can save you a lot of configuration and future maintenance.